# How to train an LSTM with multiple simultaneous time-series. Radon values over a year in 100 houses with 4 rooms

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained an LSTM neural network on 1 year's worth of radon measurement time-series data for one room in one house. I have 100 houses with 4 rooms each. How could I create a for loop to train on 70 houses (4 rooms each) to keep training the network with data rather than having 70 different LSTMs?

```
#Synthetic Radon data for 5 houses x 4 rooms each

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date_time'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31', freq='H')
#make 1000 rows for each house and roomm columns
df['house'] = np.random.choice(['01TE85', '02TE85', '03TE85', '04TE85', '05TE85'], size=len(df))
df['room'] = np.random.choice(['Living room', 'Bedroom', 'Kitchen', 'Bathroom'], size=len(df))
df['radon_short_term_avg'] = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.1, size=len(df)) 

#Filter house == 01TE85 and room == "Living room"
df = df[(df['house'] == '01TE85') & (df['room'] == 'Bedroom')]


# Convert date_time to datetime
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Set date_time as index
df = df.set_index('date_time')
radon = df["radon_short_term_avg"]

# for every 5 hours, let's predict the next hour
# X=[[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]] y = [6]
# X=[[[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]] y = [7]

# create function to create X and Y
def df_to_X_y(df, window_size):
  df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
  X = []
  y = []
  for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
    row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
    X.append(row)
    label = df_as_np[i+window_size]
    y.append(label)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)

WINDOW_SIZE = 5
X, y = df_to_X_y(radon, WINDOW_SIZE)
print(X.shape, y.shape)   

# Split data into train and test
X_train, y_train = X[:60_000], y[:60_000]
X_val, y_val = X[60_000:65_000], y[60_000:65_000]
X_test, y_test = X[65_000:], y[65_000:]

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(InputLayer((WINDOW_SIZE, 1)))
model2.add(Conv1D(64,kernel_size=1))
model2.add(Flatten())
model2.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model2.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

model2.summary()

# checkpoint    
cp2 = ModelCheckpoint('model2/', save_best_only=True)

#compile model
model2.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

# fit model
model2.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=10, callbacks=[cp2])
```

Comment: If this ends up being more of a conceptual problem than just a pure programming issue, then [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254090/858527) is a good list of StackExchange sites that have a Machine Learning focus.

Comment: I was contemplating that the question might be too open ended. I'll re-word into, how to create a for-loop to nest this model into it and train it sequentially on the data from the first 70 houses with 4 rooms each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not want to train your model on each house sequentially in a `for` loop: you're likely to run into [catastrophic forgetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference) issues (in short, by the time you're done training on your last house your model will have a bad performance on the first one). Different solutions exist to counteract this problem, but one of the easiest is to interleave the data.

To do that, instead of generating a dataset for each house then training the model sequentially on these datasets, you'll want to create a dataset containing the data for all the houses, and then train the model once on this larger dataset. The modified code for data generation would look like this:

```py
#Synthetic Radon data for 5 houses x 4 rooms each
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date_time'] = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-12-31', freq='H')
#make 1000 rows for each house and roomm columns
df['house'] = np.random.choice(['01TE85', '02TE85', '03TE85', '04TE85', '05TE85'], size=len(df))
df['room'] = np.random.choice(['Living room', 'Bedroom', 'Kitchen', 'Bathroom'], size=len(df))
df['radon_short_term_avg'] = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.1, size=len(df)) 

# create function to create X and Y
def df_to_X_y(df, window_size):
  df_as_np = df.to_numpy()
  X = []
  y = []
  for i in range(len(df_as_np)-window_size):
    row = [[a] for a in df_as_np[i:i+window_size]]
    X.append(row)
    label = df_as_np[i+window_size]
    y.append(label)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)

WINDOW_SIZE = 5

X_train, y_train = [], []
X_val, y_val = [], []
X_test, y_test = [], []
for house in df.house.unique():
    
    df_house = df[df["house"]==house]
    for room in df_house.room.unique():
        data = df_house[df_house["room"]==room]
        data = data.set_index('date_time')
        radon = data["radon_short_term_avg"]
        
        X, y = df_to_X_y(radon, WINDOW_SIZE)
        
        # Split data into train and test
        X_train.append(X[:60_000])
        y_train.append(y[:60_000])
        X_val.append(X[60_000:65_000])
        y_val.append(y[60_000:65_000])
        X_test.append(X[65_000:])
        y_test.append(y[65_000:])
        
X_train = np.vstack(X_train)
y_train = np.hstack(y_train)
X_val = np.vstack(X_val)
y_val = np.hstack(y_val)
X_test = np.vstack(X_test)
y_test = np.hstack(y_test)
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you very much, that's super helpful. What happens if each house wasn't measured for the same period of time? Can it handle that?

Comment: Sure, you simply will have to replace the constants (`60_000` and `65_000`) by dynamically computed values - for instance by taking 80% (`X[:int(0.8*len(X))]`) of the data for training, and 10% for both validation and test sets.

Comment: I'd like to give some bounty when it is available for all your help. I'm finding that X and Y have different lengths (only by 1). When I `print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_val.shape, y_val.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)` I get `(66633, 5, 1) (66632,) (8330, 5, 1) (8329,) (8332, 5, 1) (8331,)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, it's hard to tell without seeing the exact code - I'd recommend creating a new question presenting the updated code and explaining the off-by-one issue.

Comment: It happens with this code too I noticed. Do you get that too?

Comment: That was indeed a bug in my code, thanks! `np.empty` didn't behave as I expected it to. I've fixed the answer by simply appending to a list and converting the list to a numpy array only at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code works nicely. For me it says that I have some mixed data types in the tensor but I'll ask this as a separate question.